# Custom UIView drawing artifacts

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, custom-controls

I have the following problem:

I have made two custom UIViews. The first one is a bubble view used as container and which uses drawRect with CGContext methods to draw itself. The second one is a text view as subclass from UILabel used to show NSAttributedStrings (iOS 5 necessary). This text view
uses the designated subclass method of UILabel drawTextInRect:.

The text views are added to the bubble view with addSubview.
They are both using transparent UIColor (clearColor) as background. Now for performance optimizations I wanted to set the former clear background color to white.

Suddenly there are visual artifacts visible. For better debugging I set the background color now to red and blue:

[image: Problem]

As you see, there is 
- a red rectangle "Lorem", a blue rectangle "Lorem ipsum etc." and a green rectangle
  "ipsum dolor" which are all right and fine. They are the current position and size of
  my text views
- and there is a blue and red rectangle below the red "Lorem". They are the visual
  artifacts. They are exactly on the *starting* rectangle when I initialized my custom
  text view with initFrame.

I definitely moved the frame of my labels in the correct position with setFrame:. 
Still the former label rectangles are *still* drawn, but why ?
Neither [self setNeedsDisplay] nor [self setNeedsLayout] have an effect.

What is the cause of the redrawing and how do I fix it ?

Comment: "Suddenly there are visual artifacts visible" -- like what? Show us what it looked like before you added the background red and blue colours.

Comment: Where are the red and blue rectangles *supposed* to be? You haven't said.

Comment: I'm not convinced it's a great idea to subclass UILabel here. Why is that necessary? It may be causing you the problems you're having. If you post some code it gives more chance for us to help you.

Comment: @occulus: It is necessary to subclass UILabel because we need to support iOS 5 and draw NSAttributedStrings. UILabel is no problem because it supports text drawing with drawTextInRect:.